# Flushing a channel programmatically in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I have a Netty app that takes HTTP connections and streams intermittent data back to while keeping the connection open until the client closes it. I can get the app to work except that the send buffer doesn't push to the client frequently enough (and often across merged write events which causes incomplete data receipt on the other end until the next buffer is pushed, which may be a long time coming). I'd like to know if there's a way for me to write into the send buffer and force a flush to push a complete chunk of data to the client without having to close the socket.

I have looked at the bootstrap properties `tcpNoDelay`, `writeBufferHighWaterMark`, and `writeBufferLowWaterMark` (all with and without "child.") to no effect.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I have also tried the "sendBufferSize" option set to 0 as well, without change.

Comment: Tracing through the bind of the server socket, I see that bufferFactory, receiveBufferSize, reuseAddress and backlog are the only properties that can be set on the server socket side of things. I suppose I'll have to look at the bufferFactory next.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case not clear, Netty does not have a `flush()` operation.  It just writes as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can add a BufferedWriteHandler to the ChannelPipeline in order to emulate buffered write operation.

[BufferedWriteHandler web doc](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/queue/BufferedWriteHandler.html)

So long as you can maintain or obtain a reference to the pipelined instance of the BufferedWriteHandler,

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        BufferedWriteHandler bufferedWriter 
                = e.getChannel().getPipeline().get("buffer");
```

then you can programmatically flush as you like:

```
bufferedWriter.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question and it wasn't due to the socket buffer not sending the data. I was using "curl" to test the response and curl has an internal buffer that was preventing the data from being printed to the screen. This can be disabled with "-N." Entirely my own fault, but still took a while to dig through the code and trace it back to my client.